# Using UrlRewriteFilter to redirect subdomains from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: tomcat7, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I successfully redirect from HTTP to HTTPS using this UrlRewriteFilter rule:

```
   <rule>
        <condition type="scheme" operator="notequal">https</condition>
        <condition name="host" operator="equal">pokercopilot.com</condition>
        <from>^/(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://pokercopilot.com/$1</to>
    </rule>
```

In the same Tomcat web app, we have fr.pokercopilot.com, es.pokercopilot.com, etc. I'd also like to redirect them from http to https.

The current rule is redirecting every URL from http://XX.pokercopilot.com/ to https://pokercopilot.com/ - we are losing the subdomain info.

How can I do the redirect while keeping the subdomain info intact?